# Como añadir numero de pagina con FPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, this

Estoy usando FPDF pero al poner un numero de pagina me sale error, estoy usando eso:

`$this->Cell(0,10,'Pagina '$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');`

Pero en en segundo `$this` me sale error.

Me sale eso: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$this", expecting ")"`

Este es mi código completo:

```
<?php

require 'fpdf/fpdf.php';
class PDF extends FPDF
{
    function Header()
    {
        $this->Image('img/logo.png', 5, 0, 30);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
        $this->Cell(30);
        $this->Cell(120,10,"Hola",0,0,'C');

        $this->Ln(20);

    }

    function Footer()
    {
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Pagina '$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, lo tenia que concatenar.

$this->Cell(0,10,'Pagina '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');